# Find $\mathcal{O}_{\mathscr{L}(a)}$ so that $a_n\sim\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{1+a_n}}+\mathcal{O}_{\mathscr{L}(a)}(\frac{1}{n})\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: limits, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, recursion, laurent-series

> Given a recursion $a_{n+ 1}= \sqrt{1+ \dfrac{1}{1+ a_{n}}}$ with $a_{1}> 1.$ We have that
> $$a_{n}\sim\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{1+ a_{n}}}+ \mathcal{O}\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$$
> *Source*: It's an my own problem that I posted before and that received many solutions.

Call $\lim a_{n}= a,$ if I want to give an asymptotic analysis for $a_{n+ 1}- a_{n},$ that's no good since $a\not\in\mathbb{Q}.$ I think about Groebner Basis, is there way to find $\mathcal{O}_{\mathscr{L}\left ( a \right )}\left ( \dfrac{1}{n} \right )$ with $a$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $\mathscr{L}\left ( a \right ),$ how can we do that ?

Comment: When you have a big-$\mathcal{O}$ on the right-hand side, you should use $=$ instead of $\sim$.

Comment: What does your notation $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{L}(a)}$ mean? What does "that's no good since $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ mean here -- what is "no good"?

Comment: $a$ is not a nice number and it's very hard to use the Laurent Serie for it.

Comment: So we can't use $a$ directly !

Comment: That is... not true? E.g., $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, we definitely can use it in various ways, involving Taylor series around it. And you haven't explained what your notation is supposed to mean...

Comment: But $a$ is not same.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Why is it not the same? $a$ is just the solution to a quadratic equation. (And also still no idea what the notation you used is supposed to mean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\left| {a_{n + 1}  - a_n } \right| = \frac{{\left| {a_n  - a_{n - 1} } \right|}}{{(1 + a_n )(1 + a_{n - 1} )\left( {\sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{{1 + a_n }}}  + \sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{{1 + a_{n - 1} }}} } \right)}} \le \frac{{\left| {a_n  - a_{n - 1} } \right|}}{8}
$$
since $a_n>1$ for all $n\geq 1$. Thus,
$$
\left| {a_{n + 1}  - a_n } \right| \le \frac{{\left| {a_2  - a_1 } \right|}}{{8^{n - 1} }} \le \frac{{4\sqrt 6  + 8a_1 }}{{8^n }},
$$
i.e.,
$$
a_{n + 1}  = a_n  +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{8^n }}} \right).
$$